# Вложенный SQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Стоит задача двумя запросами вставить 2 записи.
Во второй нужно использовать новый ID первой записи. Как сделать? Помогите.

```
INSERT INTO `sys_options_cats` (`name`) VALUES ('ИМЯ')

INSERT INTO `sys_options` (`Name`, `VALUE`, `kateg`) 
VALUES ('sms_auth_enable', 'on', SELECT `ID` FROM `sys_options_cats` WHERE `name`='ИМЯ' LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Так Вы же написали то, что нужно. Только заключите SELECT ... LIMIT 1 в скобки. И точки с запятыми поставьте. Или я Вас неправильно понял?

Comment: Точно) Про скобки забыл. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `sys_options_cats` (`name`) VALUES ('ИМЯ');

INSERT INTO `sys_options` (`Name`, `VALUE`, `kateg`) 
VALUES ('sms_auth_enable', 'on', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: Это сработает если между этими двумя запросами в базе не произойдёт другой вставки. Лучший вариант, это как в вопросе. Только со скобками. Ставлю +, но ответ неверный

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() возвращает последний ID, вставленный в соединении. Так что ответ верный.